# I can't find these converstation in tafsir ibn kathir?

Tags: tafseer, source-identification

in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6Rm5oLHWKk) a sheikh told a story about conversation between Adam AS and Allah
The conversation goes following.

```
He Said My LORD Did You Not 
Create Me With Your Own Two Hands?

And ALLAH Said, Yes

He Said Did You Not Breathe Into Me
The Breath Of Life And Cause Me To Live?

And ALLAH Says, Yes

Did You Not When I Sneezed, Say YARHAMUK ALLAH
"MAY ALLAH HAVE MERCY ON YOU" Yes I Did Say That

Then ADAM (A.S) Asked A Very Wise Question
To ALLAH (S.W.T) That Explains Us

He Said When You Created Me And You Placed Me In That
Garden And You Told Me Not To Eat From That Tree

Didn't You Already Know
I Was Gonna Eat From It?

And See The Wisdom Of ADAM (A.S) Didn't You 
Know I Was Gonna Eat From That Tree

You See ADAM (A.S) Understood That ALLAH Knew

Before Creating Anything, That He Was Gonna Create ADAM (A.S)
He Was Gonna Put Him In The Garden And Him And His Wife

And They Were Gonna Eat From That Tree Even Though
They Were Told Not To Do So, ALLAH Knew

So ALLAH Said, Yes
l Knew You Were Going To Do It

So ADAM (A.S) Said Then Can You Not Forgiven Me 
For That, And Put Me Back In That Garden One Day?

And ALLAH Said, Yes

And He Taught Nim The Very Famous Words

My Lord I Have Wronged My Own Soul And If You Do Not Forgive Me
And Have Mercy On Me, Surely I Will Be One Of The Losers
```

This conversation supposed to be in tafsir ibn kathir, tafsir of (Qur'an 7:23) But i checked and can't find the same conversation as in YouTube. **Do anyone know where this conversation is from?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mentioned in Tafsir Ibn Kathir under the verse [2:37](https://quran.com/2/37).

> وقال السدي ، عمن حدثه ، عن ابن عباس : فتلقى آدم من ربه كلمات ، قال : قال آدم ، عليه السلام : يا رب ، ألم تخلقني بيدك ؟ قيل له : بلى . ونفخت في من روحك ؟ قيل له : بلى . وعطست فقلت : يرحمك الله ، وسبقت رحمتك غضبك ؟ قيل له : بلى ، وكتبت علي أن أعمل هذا ؟ قيل له : بلى . قال : أفرأيت إن تبت هل أنت راجعي إلى الجنة ؟ قال : نعم .
>
> As-Suddi said that Ibn `Abbas commented on,
>
> > (Then Adam received from his Lord Words)
>
> "Adam said, 'O Lord! Did You not created me with Your Own Hands' He said, 'Yes.' He said, 'And blow life into me' He said, 'Yes.' He said, 'And when I sneezed, You said, 'May Allah grant you His mercy.' Does not Your mercy precede Your anger' He was told, 'Yes.' Adam said, 'And You destined me to commit this evil act' He was told, 'Yes.' He said, 'If I repent, will You send me back to Paradise' Allah said, 'Yes.'' '
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura2-aya37.html#katheer) -    ([English Translation](https://quran.com/2:37/tafsirs/en-tafisr-ibn-kathir))</sup>

Comment: Jazak allahu khair brother